# How to take the text of novel as raw_input and put it in ''' '''

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

```
def hashStory():
    message = raw_input('Enter Story')
    dictionary = {}
    for i in message.upper():
        dictionary.setdefault(i, 0)
        dictionary[i] = dictionary[i] + 1
    return dictionary
```

this code, when used on short strings like 'Hello, how are you', returns this.

```
{'A': 1, ' ': 3, 'E': 2, 'H': 2, 'L': 2, 'O': 3, 'R': 1, 'U': 1, 'W': 1, 'Y': 1}
```

But when I want to hash the letters in a story such as this.

[RomeoAndJuliet](http://automatetheboringstuff.com/files/rj.txt)

the punctuation gets in the way. How can I use raw_input to take the words in triple quotes.

Comment: Have you tried reading until there isn't anything else to read?

Comment: yes https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input